# Where to start an absolute beginner for Windows 8 App Development?

Tags: windows-8

I want to learn Windows 8 app development by going through some already built apps(if available).So anyone could suggest where should i start for this.Suggestion of tutorials/links/resource would also helpful.

EDIT: I am an absolute beginner in Windows 8 App Development. All I know is that we can develop Windows 8 Apps either with JavaScript/CSS or with C#/VB + XAML. As I do have some knowledge on C# & XAML . I would like to stick with C#/XAML development. So, please suggest me accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go to the official [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/) and study everything from there. In particular you should find this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/br211386) helpful since it contains links to a few tutorials in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft came up with various resources in the internet so that absoluely anyone can develop windows apps.One such thing is [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://microsoftvirtualacademy.com/).Where after you sign up ,you can add your needed/favorite courses  to your learning plan and learn in your own pace.